# Disable Cmder hotkeys in specific window/tab

Tags: emacs, conemu, cmder

I'd like to use Emacs as my command line editor in Cmder. Unfortunately Cmder's hotkeys get in the way of Emacs'.

Is there a way to disable Cmder hotkeys on a per window/tab/current task running basis? Or somehow give the Emacs hotkeys a higher priority?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. You should change ConEmu hotkeys.

Comment: Well, too bad. Thanks for the definitive answer though.